# Is it ok to say "in order to climb over the barrier, you need to put one of your legs on top of it and then twist or turn your body over it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You are training your child to climb over a barrier. Sometimes, he just hangs himself on one side without knowing what to do next.

[image]

Is it ok to say to your child "**in order to climb over the barrier, you need to put one of your legs on top of it and then twist or turn your body over it**"?

Comment: What specifically is your problem? The choice between "twist" or "turn"? Something else? Could you [edit] your post to clarify?

Comment: You throw one leg over the barrier and then slide down the other side. No twisting or turning necessary.